# typescript issue, property comes from an index signature, no form

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm creating a tasks-manager to learn typescript / angular / node. We can create a list, and assign some tasks to the list.

Some code:

> ```
> import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
> import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
> import { TaskService } from 'src/app/services/task.service';
>
> @Component({
>   selector: 'app-tasks-manager',
>   templateUrl: './tasks-manager.component.html',
>   styleUrls: ['./tasks-manager.component.css']
> })
> export class TasksManagerComponent implements OnInit {
>
>   lists: any;
>   tasks: any;
>
>   constructor(private taskService: TaskService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
>
>   ngOnInit(): void {
>
>     this.route.params.subscribe(
>       (params: Params) => {
>         console.log(params);
>         this.taskService.getTasks(params.listId).subscribe((tasks: any) => {
>           this.tasks = tasks;
>         })
>       }
>     )
>
>     this.taskService.getLists().subscribe((lists: any) => {
>       this.lists = lists;
>     })
>   }
> }
> ```

The error is on the lines :
this.taskService.getTasks(params.listId).subscribe((tasks: any) => {

> ```
>           this.tasks = tasks;
>         })
> ```

The error: Property 'listId' comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['listId']

I've already tried to change (params.listId) by (params?.['listId']), also by (params['listId']). None of these solutions work. On my API, I can access of the lists added on my database, but not to the tasks associated to the lists.

More codes :

> ```
> > import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; import { WebRequestService
> > } from './web-request.service';
> > 
> > @Injectable({   providedIn: 'root' }) export class TaskService {
> > 
> >   constructor( private webRequestService: WebRequestService) { }
> > 
> >   /* purpose: sending a web request to create a new list */  
> > createList(title:string) {
> >     return this.webRequestService.post('lists', { title });   }
> > 
> >   /* purpose: get(read) the lists created */   getLists() {
> >     return this.webRequestService.get('lists');   }
> > 
> >   /* purpose: get(read) the tasks corresponding to a specific list */ 
> > getTasks(listId: string) {
> >     return this.webRequestService.get(`lists/${listId}`);   } }
> ```

Thank you very very much by advance for any response. I'm still searching, every response can be usefull I guess.

Comment: Probably easier to simply make your own type instead of using Params? Also, nested subscriptions, not a good idea..

Comment: Weird, it was supposed to work with `params['listId']`.

Comment: @AllanJuan i tried again with params['listId']. This way i have no error in my IDE but I face httpErrorResponse . So maybe the code is good, and the issue is somewhere else. I'll search, i still have a lot of things to learn :) Thank you for your response

Comment: If you're getting an HTTP Error Response, it's because the API returned an error. That might be an error on the API, or maybe you're sending an invalid request.